# A filter on a compact set with only one cluster point must converge.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter on a compact topological space $(X,\tau)$ and $\mathcal{F}$ has only one cluster point, $x\in X$ (recall $x$ is a cluster point of $\mathcal{F}$ means that $x\in \overline {F}$ for every $F\in\mathcal{F}).$

I am trying to show that $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow x $ (i.e. that $\mathcal{F}$ contains every open set that contains $x$).

I am not sure how to make any significant progress. I know that if $X$ is compact than every ultrafilter on $X$ converges and for an ultrafilter we have that the limit points and cluster points are the same. So if I could show something like $\mathcal{F}$ is an **ultrafilter** then we would be done. But I am not sure this is even true.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that $\mathcal{F}$ converges to $x$ is to show $\mathscr{V}(x) \subset \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathscr{V}(x)$ is the neighbourhood filter of $x$ (V from voisinage).

So you can show that if $\mathscr{V}(x) \not\subset \mathcal{F}$, then $\mathcal{F}$ has a cluster point other than $x$. $\mathscr{V}(x) \not\subset \mathcal{F}$ means there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that $V \notin \mathcal{F}$. By the filter properties, we can assume $V$ open, since $\operatorname{int} V \in \mathcal{F} \implies V \in \mathcal{F}$. Then the family

$$\{ F \setminus V : F \in \mathcal{F}\}$$

is a filter on the compact set $X\setminus V$, hence has a cluster point $y \in X\setminus V$. Then $y$ is also a cluster point of $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Another way to look at it (although it's not as good since it uses some axiom of choice) is the following : if $V\notin \mathcal{F}$, there is an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ containing $\mathcal{F}$ with $X\setminus V \in \mathcal{U}$. $\mathcal{U}$ converges since $X$ is compact, but not to $x$. Therefore $\mathcal{F}$ has another cluster point.

Comment: @Max how do you know that such an ultrafilter exists? I have asked this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2347043/if-mathcalf-is-a-filter-on-x-show-that-mathcalf-subseteq-mathcalu

Comment: @Dman : I have answered your question there